# Formula or macro to group cells according to their values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, vba

I am on a spreadsheet that needs to retitle cells based on the cell value and the values of the cells below it. Basically I have the below column, which is filled by a formula that links to another spreadsheet.

```
Column A
EE
EE
SP
EE
CH
CH
EE
SP
CH
CH
EE
```

- For an cell that has `EE`, and for which the cell below it is `EE`, then the first cell should read "EE Only".
- For any cell that has `EE`, and for which the cell below it is `SP`, which is then followed by another `EE`, then the first two cells should read "EE+SP".
- For any cell `EE` where the cell(s) below it are `CH`, then those cells should read "EE+CH".
- And for any cell `EE` where the cells below it are `SP` and `CH`, then all of those cells should read "EE+FAM".

The above column should then look like:

```
Column A
EE Only
EE+SP
EE+SP
EE+CH
EE+CH
EE+CH
EE+FAM
EE+FAM
EE+FAM
EE+FAM
EE Only
```

It's a long table of values, and quite honestly I'm not even sure what the best way to go about this is.

Do I need to create a table of values to lookup against, or is there a macro that would be able to handle this?

Comment: You could do this with VBA.  You're going to need a loop construct to go through each row.  For each row look at the cell and determine if it contains EE or not.  If it is an EE row then set a flag and use a second loop to work your way down until the end or the next EE.  That will determine what you call this row and the following rows until the end or the next EE row.

Comment: Do you have any code that could work? If I sent up a loop construct that finds EE, it seems like I would need multiple secondary loops to see if the group of cells should be renamed EE+SP, or EE+FAM etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your input example:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"EE",B1="EE+FAM"),"EE+FAM",IF(AND(A2="EE",OR(A3="EE",A3="")),"EE Only",IF(OR(AND(A1="EE",A2="SP",A3="EE"),AND(A2="EE",A3="SP",A4="EE")),"EE+SP",IF(OR(A2="CH",A3="CH"),"EE+CH",IF(AND(A2="EE",A3<>"EE"),"EE+FAM","")))))
```

should derive your output example.

Comment: Hi pnuts, I'm not sure your formula works completely. I changed the B1 to A1 in the first AND statement, as I think thats what you meant, but when I plug it in, the IF statements don't seem to work. I'll keep playing around with your idea though, thanks for the help!

Comment: Wouldn't that be a circular reference then, if I put the formula into `B1`, `A1` or `A2`?